# how to change images on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, image, mouseover

I am a very newbie in javascript and have a problem with changing images on mouse over.
It must changes pictures on mouse over respectively by add and remove "current" class.
I had a try to do that with javascript but nothing happened.
any help please.
thanks.

```js
<script>
  $('.images-hover').each(function () {
            var $product = $(this);
            var $thumbs = $product.find('.images-box');
            var $images = $thumbs.find('img');

            if ($images.length <= 1)
                return;

            var interval, timeout;

            var imageCallback = function () {
                var $current = $thumbs.find('img.current');
                var $next = $current.next();

                if ($next.index() < 0)
                    $next = $images.first();

                $current.removeClass('current');
                $next.addClass('current');
            };

            var setCurrent = function () {
                $images.removeClass('current');
                $images.first().addClass('current');
            };

            setCurrent();

            $product.hover(function () {
                timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    imageCallback();
                    interval = setInterval(imageCallback, 2500);
                }, 200);
            }, function () {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                clearInterval(interval);
                setCurrent();
            });
        });
</script>
```

```css
.images-hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.images-hover img.current {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-hover">
  <div class="images-box">
    <a href="#" >
      <img class="current" src="img/image1.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image4.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="images-hover">
  <div class="images-box">
    <a href="#" class="images-hover" >
      <img class="current" src="img/image5.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image6.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image7.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image8.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check your browser console for Any errors?

Comment: @LearningPhase Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Are you including the jquery files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following on the snippet (now it works):

- remove `<script>` tag from js section
- add jquery reference

Also note that your script has to run after the html elements have been rendered. You can do that by placing your script on the end of the page or by using document ready event.

```
$(function() {
  /* your script goes here, page html has been loaded */
});
```

```js
  $('.images-hover').each(function () {
            var $product = $(this);
            var $thumbs = $product.find('.images-box');
            var $images = $thumbs.find('img');

            if ($images.length <= 1)
                return;

            var interval, timeout;

            var imageCallback = function () {
                var $current = $thumbs.find('img.current');
                var $next = $current.next();

                if ($next.index() < 0)
                    $next = $images.first();

                $current.removeClass('current');
                $next.addClass('current');
            };

            var setCurrent = function () {
                $images.removeClass('current');
                $images.first().addClass('current');
            };

            setCurrent();

            $product.hover(function () {
                timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    imageCallback();
                    interval = setInterval(imageCallback, 2500);
                }, 200);
            }, function () {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                clearInterval(interval);
                setCurrent();
            });
        });
```

```css
.images-hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.images-hover img.current {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images-hover">
  <div class="images-box">
    <a href="#" >
      <img class="current" src="img/image1.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image4.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="images-hover">
  <div class="images-box">
    <a href="#" class="images-hover" >
      <img class="current" src="img/image5.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image6.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image7.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img src="img/image8.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Answer Resolved The problem but I have not reputation yet to +1 it. sorry. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using Jquery methods. To change the images with JQuery you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.images-hover').each(function () {
        var $product = $(this);
        var $thumbs = $product.find('.images-box');
        var $images = $thumbs.find('img');

        if ($images.length <= 1)
            return;

        var interval, timeout;

        var imageCallback = function () {
            var $current = $thumbs.find('img.current');
            var $next = $current.next();

            if ($next.index() < 0)
                $next = $images.first();

            $current.removeClass('current');
            $next.addClass('current');
        };

        var setCurrent = function () {
            $images.removeClass('current');
            $images.first().addClass('current');
        };

        setCurrent();

        $product.hover(function () {
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                imageCallback();
                interval = setInterval(imageCallback, 2500);
            }, 200);
        }, function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            clearInterval(interval);
            setCurrent();
        });
    });
});
```

but you will need to import jquery before with:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you want to try only with javascript you can check the onmouseover event, a brief [tutorial is on w3schools about it.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp), but you would need to change the function so it doesn't use jquery methods.